# cloning elements, avoiding more than one clone at a time when adding

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/p57hm/

I simply want one more clone on each click. Did i miss something obvious_ Thanks

Script:

```
$(function(){

    $('input').click(function(){
        $('.cloneitem').clone().appendTo('#container');
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="clone it"/>

<div id="container"></div>

<div class="cloneitem">clone</div>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/p57hm/1/

```
$(function(){

    $('input').click(function(){
        $('.cloneitem:first').clone().appendTo('#container');
    });

});
```

Currently you are cloning all the elements that have the class `.cloneitem` but you only want 1 at a time, so you don't want to select all the `.cloneItem` but just the first one, and clone that one.

Answer (score 5):

`$('.cloneitem')` selects all elements with `cloneitem` class.

use `.first()`:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $('.cloneitem').first().clone().appendTo('#container');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your clones still have the class `cloneitem` so are therefore being cloned again.
Either remove this class or change the selector so it does not include them.

Something like this, adding the class clones and filtering out those items:

```
$(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        $('.cloneitem').not('.cloned').clone().addClass('cloned').appendTo('#container');
    });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/p57hm/4/

Comment: $('.cloneitem') might still be more than one element. Could be good idea to use an ID rather than a class for the element template (element to clone).

Answer (score 2):

You are cloning an element with class "cloneitem" and then also appending the cloned element with the same class causing issues for the next clone.

```
$(function() {

    $('input').click(function(){
        $('.cloneitem').first().clone().removeClass('cloneItem').appendTo('#container');
    }); // edited

});
```

Comment: You should remove the `.first()`, as it is unnessary, because the clones cloneItem class is removed, they won't be cloned anyway. That way multiple items can be cloned at once, if so desired.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Add an id to the div that you want to clone that way it is unique. An element can only have one id but many classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning all the elements with a 'cloneitem' class, so in the first time it clones once, in the second time it clone two..
U can fix it by filtering only the first object like this:

```
$(function(){

    $('input').click(function(){
        $('.cloneitem').first().clone().appendTo('#container');
    });

});
```

You can also always select the last one:

```
$('.cloneitem').last().clone().appendTo('#container');
```

Or just bind .clone() to the first item:

```
$('.cloneitem:first').clone().appendTo('#container');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $("#addmore").on('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("tr:eq(1)").clone().appendTo("tbody");        
        });
```

//you can use :eq(index) selector to target which row you want to clone.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){
    var clone = $('.cloneitem').clone();
    $('input').click(function(){
        clone.clone().appendTo('#container');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tZuDe/