# How do I clone an element without doubling the number of elements every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have 2 box's, divA and divB. Everytime divB is clicked, I want one divA to be cloned. This works fine the first time with my current code, but then it doubles the number of divA's everytime after. How do I stop this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.divB').click(function() {
        // fade out divB when clicked
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        // Then clone divA and add to body
        $(".divA").clone('true').appendTo("body");
        // Then add a new divB to the body after the cloned divA
        $(".divB").clone('true').appendTo("body");
    });
 });
```

Comment: Actually really sorry people, just found this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298138/cloning-elements-avoiding-more-than-one-clone-at-a-time-when-adding

Answer (score 2):

Keep an external reference with 1 element reference

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $divB1 = $('.divB').first();
    var $divA1 = $('.divA').first();
    $('.divB').click(function () {
        // fade out divB when clicked
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        // Then clone divA and add to body
        $divA1.clone(true).appendTo("body");
        // Then add a new divB to the body after the cloned divA
        $$divB1.clone(true).appendTo("body");
    });
});
```

Also the argument is boolean `true` not string literal `'true'`

Comment: `$divB1.clone(true).appendTo("body");` should be `$divA1...`