# My row add multiple time after press add button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Before press add button it shows already one row with three input boxes and one delete button, when I `add` button press it adds a one-row now I have two rows when I press add button `second time` it shows `4 rows`  and after I press the `third time` it shows `8 rows`[image]

My code:

```
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
        <h3>Add Video</h3>
         <form id="insertvideo" method="post">
         <table id="addrow" width="100%">
          <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success addButton col-3 offset-1" value="add"/></td>
          <tr class="clonetr">
                <td>Video Title<input type="text" id="videotitle" name="videotitle[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td>Video description<input type="text"  id="videodesc" name="videodesc[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td>Video Links<input type="text"  id="videolink" name="videolink[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" value="delete"/></td>
          </tr>
         </table>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
<script>
   $(function(){
    $(".addButton").click(function(){
        $('.clonetr').closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#addrow");
    });

    $(".deleteButton").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to add only one row after the `add` button is press.

Comment: Are you loading current table page using ajax?

Comment: possible duplication [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298138/cloning-elements-avoiding-more-than-one-clone-at-a-time-when-adding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because you every time clone all existing `tr`.** Just clone last `tr` and append it.

Another point is that you have to show delete button when there is more than one `tr`. because if you delete all tr than you cannot use `add` button for cloning.

```js
$(function(){
    $(".addButton").click(function(){
        $('.clonetr:last').clone(true).appendTo("#addrow");
    });

    $(".deleteButton").click(function(){
        if($('.deleteButton').length > 1){
        
           $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
        <h3>Add Video</h3>
         <form id="insertvideo" method="post">
         <table id="addrow" width="100%">
          <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success addButton col-3 offset-1" value="add"/></td>
          <tr class="clonetr">
                <td>Video Title<input type="text" id="videotitle" name="videotitle[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td>Video description<input type="text"  id="videodesc" name="videodesc[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td>Video Links<input type="text"  id="videolink" name="videolink[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" value="delete"/></td>
          </tr>
         </table>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: I want to show at list one row but it is removed the first row after `delete` button is press

Comment: ok, so you have to remove delete button when there is last tr. see im am going to show it here.

Comment: run the updated code. it will never remove last one

Answer (score 1):

change closest to first

`$('.clonetr').closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#addrow");`

to

`$('.clonetr').first("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#addrow");`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is after button call. In your code, you get all "tr" and clone it!
Well, now, after call add, using this with closest("tr"), clone it and after using append.

Change your code like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".addButton").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#addrow");
    });

    $(".deleteButton").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know you're adding Html content after the page load, so click won't work for that tag...No worries we have a solution as below:

and find a solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3gwkxd8s/16/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var Data_to_clone = $('.cloning-table tbody').html();
    $(".addButton").click(function(){
        $(Data_to_clone).appendTo(".cloning-table");
    });

    $(".cloning-table").on('click','.deleteButton',function(){
        $(this).parents(".clonetr").remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
        <h3>Add Video</h3>
         <form id="insertvideo" method="post">
         <table id="addrow" width="100%">
         <tr>
          <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success addButton col-3 offset-1" value="add"/></td>
          </tr></table>
             <table class="cloning-table" width="100%">
             <tbody>
          <tr class="clonetr">
                <td>Video Title<input type="text" id="videotitle" name="videotitle[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td>Video description<input type="text"  id="videodesc" name="videodesc[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td>Video Links<input type="text"  id="videolink" name="videolink[]" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" value="delete"/></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Let me know if still, you need any changes